# How to overcome ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID in JS?

Tags: javascript, fetch, ssl-certificate

I use:

```html
<script src="https://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js"></script>
```

and the library isn't downloaded. In the Network tab its header has this warning: [Provisional headers are shown](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/?utm_source=devtools#provisional-headers)
. I try

```js
fetch("https://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js")
```

and I get the error ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID. Now there are [many ways to fix this in browser](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/net-err_cert_date_invalid/), but I wonder if this can be solved in JS only?